# start MUSIC in python

Tags: python-3.x, oop, audio-player

I need source code that loads and starts music in python without importing any modules at all. Is that possible or should I try other languages like c# or c++ because every modules are written in cpython!

Answer (score 0):

First off I think it depends on the type of file but if your file of choice is WAV, AU, AIFF, MP3, CSL, SD, SMP, or NIST/Sphere, you can use The Snack Sound Toolkit. I know you asked for not using a module but this is very good and can be used on a plethora of files. It works like this:

```
snd = Sound()
snd.read('ex1.wav')
snd.play()
```

Also it can also be used to show the graphical representation of the sound by this:

```
c = SnackCanvas()
c.pack()
c.create_waveform(0, 0, sound=snd)
```